Node.js app can't reach Elastic Bean Stalk environmental variables
I've deployed my node.js app to AWS EBS successfully, it works, the app is accessible via EBS URL, except DB connection. It fails because my app can't read environmental variables that are configured in EBS environment.
Here is the code that reads the env-vars.
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import "dotenv";

console.log(process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME);
console.log(process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD);
console.log(process.env.POSTGRES_HOST);
console.log(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT);
console.log(process.env);


const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  "postgres",
  process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME!,
  process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD!,
  {
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
    port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT) || 5432,
  },
);

export default sequelize;

I can see process.env printed in EC2 console, but it doesn't contain 4 parameters I need to connect to DB:

And here is the env-vars from EBS:

I had an idea that variables are set in EBS, and app is running on EC2 instance (it was created automatically by EBS during deployment), but AWS docs say that the variables should be available by default.
Any ideas on what is going wrong with that?
